# I didn't understand the change proposed in DR 2145 for [dcl.fct.def.general]/2

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The change proposed in [DR 2145](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2145) was responsible for the change in [[dcl.fct.def.general]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.general#2) from C++14 to C++17, as follows:

C++14:

> The declarator in a function-definition shall have the form
>         D1 ( *parameter-declaration-clause* )
>   *cv-qualifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub> *ref-qualifier*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>                *exception-specification*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>   *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>   *trailing-return-type*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>   as described in 8.3.5. A function
>   shall be defined only in namespace or class scope.

C++17:

> In a function-definition, either `void` *declarator* `;` or *declarator* `;`
>   shall be a well-formed function declaration as described in 11.3.5. A
>   function shall be defined only in namespace or class scope.

Frankly, I didn't understand the motivation for the change, neither the new wording in C++17.

Comment: Could you maybe tell us *what* you don't understand?

Comment: Well I've said that above. I didn't understand the reason for the change, nor did I understand the new wording in C++17. But I can tell you I understand what was written in C++14.

Comment: The DR has *However, in practice implementations accept a parenthesized declarator in a function definition* as the reason.  If you follow [*declarator*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#nt:declarator) it gives you the same but also includes more options.

Comment: The intention is to allow stuff like `int (f()) { return 1; }` which is banned by the previous wording but allowed in practice. But this new wording seems broken, too.

Comment: @T.C. That seems to be the answer. I didn't know about the `f()` in between parentheses. Thank you..

Comment: @T.C. The grammar in C++14 already accepted the `f()` in beween parentheses. I can see that the definition for the grammar production _noptr-declarator_  in N4140 is equal to its definition in C++ 17, i.e., both contain the production `(` _ptr-declarator_ `)` that allows the alluded extra parentheses.

Comment: The grammar allows it. It's the sentence you quoted from C++14 that disallows it by prescribing that only declarators matching the exact form it specifies are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As T.C. pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071198/i-didnt-understand-the-change-proposed-in-dr-2145-for-dcl-fct-def-general-2#comment89132939_51071198),

> The intention is to allow stuff like `int (f()) { return 1; }` which is banned by the previous wording but allowed in practice.